# Calculate sum of Map[String, BigInt]

Tags: scala, dictionary, bigint

I have a map which consists of BigInt values and I want to calculate general sum of these values and return it in map as a value. I have been trying to use sum method or reduce but each time I get either get sums for each key or value reduce is not a member of BigInt. How can I do this?
Here is the code I used with reduce:

```
def calculateSum(input: Map[String, BigInt]): Map[String, BigInt] = {
    val sum = data
      .map { case (name, id) =>
        name -> input.get(name).sum
      }
      .map{ case (name, count) =>
       "result" -> count.reduce(_ + _)
      }
    sum
  }
```

**data** type: Map[ String, Int]

**input** example:
("category 1" -> 0, "category 2" -> 0, "category 3" -> 430, "category 4" -> 0, "category 5" -> 0, "category 6" -> 1400, "category 7" -> 0)

**output** example:
("result1" -> 1830)

Comment: What is `db`, what is `data`, what is `value`, what are their types? How does a sample input look like, what would be the expected output for that input? - The question is not clear at all.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand, what are the contents of `data`? How does it affects the results? It seems you only want to sum all value, thus just `input.valuesIterator.sum` should do the job, but then why the output is another **Map**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to get the sum of values which can be done like this:

```scala
def calculateSum(input: Map[String, BigInt]): Map[String, BigInt] = {
  val sum = input.values.sum
  Map("result" -> sum)
}
```